# Programmatically invoking a Popover not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, popover, uistoryboardsegue

My goal in the following is to have a Popover appear via one of two paths.

The first explicitly when a button is pressed and the second is when a countdown timer expires.

The first is working - I have a Storyboard Segue configured as a Popover and tied to the button. When the button is pressed, a Popover appears. Great!

The second is not - I have a timer (NSTimer) that calls - every second - a method that updates a label with the number of seconds left in the countdown. When the countdown reaches zero I would like to automatically invoke the popover. I've tried two approaches - one is to invoke the button programmatically (`[self popoverButton:self]`). The other is using the following code:

```
PopViewController *myPopVC = [[PopViewController alloc] init];
UIStoryboardSegue *aSegue = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"popoverSegue" source:self destination:myPopVC];
[self prepareForSegue:aSegue sender:self];
[aSegue perform];
```

Neither of these two approaches is working so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the segue has an identifier set in the storyboard then call the performSegueWithIdentifier method.  See this answer for an example on how to do this when your timer expires.

[Call another view when user taps on pin in mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834047/call-another-view-when-user-taps-on-pin-in-mapview/10834135#10834135)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. The 'performSegueWithIdentifier' approach worked for me.

Cheers.
Tony.

Answer (score 0):

use popOverController's method:

```
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

you will need to create a CGRect with the position you want to popOver's arrow pointing to. Or you can assign to the Frame of any UIView inside the view.